# I am getting my output on my console , but cannot get it on screen . Its a code, which counts no. of characters on input string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, ecmascript-6

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACNbl.png) Its a program , which counts no. of characters on input string. everything is coming correct on console, but i am not able to get it on UI. I have tried getting count.valueOf() , but it doesnot seems right.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const CharCount = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [print, setPrint] = useState(false)

    const count= (value)=>{
        const result = [...value].reduce((a, e) => { a[e] = a[e] ? a[e] + 1 : 1; return a }, [])
        setPrint(false)
        console.log(result)
        return result      
    }

    const clickHandler=()=>{
        setPrint(true)
    }

  return (
    <div>
        <input type="text" value={data} onChange={ e=> setData(e.target.value)}/>
        <div><button onClick={clickHandler}>CLICK!</button></div>
        
    {
     print?
      <h1> 
            {count(data)}
      </h1> : ""
    }
    </div>
  )
}

export default CharCount
```

Comment: you're setting `print` in `clickHandler` to `true` then back again to `false` in `count` print is therefore always `false` and the number is never shown

Comment: the purpose of print, setprint is to print the whole value of text box, when clicked the submit button. when its set to false in count, that means everytime, user types in input box, it will not set every letter , but when it sets to true in clickHandler after clicking the button, it acquires the entire value, then sends it back to count to get the entire result in one go. you can check on console

Comment: `print` is always `false` since you're setting it to true then immediately to false again when `count` is called. That's why you don't see the value, I commented it out in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-sun-ppye1g?file=/src/App.js) to demonstrate this.

Comment: whenever you are typing each letter by letter, print is false. As soon as Button is clicked , it sets to true. It will set to true till user types again in input box. As you tried to put 12, to check its value to true, i would like to print the result , as soon as user clicks the button.

Comment: please check the image i have just added

Answer (score 0):

`count(data)` return an array , try this

```
print && (
  <>
    count(data).map(val => (<h1>{val}</h1> )) 
  </>
)
```

Comment: still not getting on ui